# iPhone 5 problem, "No Service" and not being recognised by iTunes

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, itunes

I've recently purchased a second hand iPhone 5. They demonstrated the phone making calls before I purchased it.

Unfortunately the phone **isn't being recognised by iTunes**, *and* is also very frequently showing me the message **"No service"**. I did however very briefly have service earlier today, enough to send and receive a couple of SMS's.

The things I have tried are:

- Restarting laptop,
- Trying another laptop,
- Uninstalling and reinstalling iTunes (on both laptops),
- "Reset Network Settings,
- Rebooting phone,
- Airplane mode on / off,
- 4G on / off,
- Updating all software,
- Trying to turn off automatic carrier selection, but I get the message "Unable to load network list",
- "Reset All Settings",
- Trying many mixes of restarting with cables in and out and every different USB port available to me,
- Offering my lunch to the gods.

The software involved is:

- iTunes 12.1.50
- iOS 8.1.2
- OS X 10.10.2

I've also checked and the phone is definitely unlocked, and marked as last activated yesterday when I first tried to use it.

I would be greatly appreciative of any further suggestions.

Comment: Did you try with another SIM card? Probably won't help with the iTunes issue, but the "no service" error might just be a buggy SIM card.

Comment: After seeing some comments here: http://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/21wjdz/itunes_will_not_recognise_iphone/ I tried this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263 and this appears to have solved the connection problem. Still got "No Service" issues. Will try a new SIM tonight. Thanks!